# How to monitor CPU-GPU temperature and load in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, gpu, monitoring

I am used to monitor system's characteristics by `lm-sensors hddtemp psensor` in Ubuntu Linux. 
I would like to get a similar monitoring setting as `psensor` in Windows 10 Enterprise.

My processor is the third generation i7, i7-3770, with socket 1155. 
The Open Hardware Monitor -application does not support it. 
It would be great some software which supports my CPU. 
I am using GTX 9** GPUs.

I am experimenting both answers. The most relevant part of CPU monitoring is to estimate the power usage. 
OHM does not have drivers for i7-3770 but it still tries to estimate the power of my processor, which is a wrong way of doing these estimations. Max temperatures of CPU in different programs

- BIOS UEFI utility - EZ Mode. CPU temperature +35 C in 5 min running but this is only physical CPU temperature so may ignore core 2 and 3.
- Windows 10 Enterprise, [OHM](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) at rest. **Physical 38 C, 0 33 C, 1 55 C, 2 75 C, 3 110 C**. Impossible!
- Ubuntu 14.10, psensor at rest. Physical 38 C, 0 33 C, 1 38 C, 2 34 C, 3 33 C.
- Ubuntu 14.10, psensor at CPU heavy load for 5 minutes. 60 C, 0 51, 1 67 C, 2 67 C, 3 54 C,
- Windows 10 Enterprise, CPUid.

### CPUid and OHM simultaneously in Windows 10 Enterprise

[image]

A ticket sent about the case [here](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/issues/769) in OHM. Issue sent also in freenode's #hardware-monitor channel.

---

How can you monitor characteristics of CPU and GPU in Windows 10 Enterprise?

Comment: Downvoter! Leave a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a program called [Open Disk Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/).  It is able to list information from the various sensors located in your computer's hardware.

Comment: I updated the body of my question. My CPU is i7-3770 which does not seem to be supported by the software. It would be great to have some software which supports my system.

Comment: Try this one.  If it works, I will post it as an answer: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html

Comment: @EricJohnson Oh  Eric, I just posted that as an answer. Don't be so shy to post it right away ;)

Comment: @StaticStorm After posting one not working one, I did not want to post another answer

Comment: @EricJohnson oh yes, I missed the fact that you posted the initial answer, my bad. :) I thought you only commented.

Answer (score 2):

I keep both CPUID HW Monitor and TechPowerUp GPU-Z on my machine. HW Monitor I like that you can see current sensor information for Value as well as Min and Max values, all displayed side by side. Lots's of information (also, it's very similar to Open Disk Monitor). The reason I like keeping GPU-Z is that it provides a wealth of information about the GPU itself in addition to displaying sensor setting. This could come in handy should you need to provide card information when requesting tech assistance. Both seem to be wonderful products and run well on WIN 10 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend HW Monitor from CPUID. It has a freeware version and can provided you with temperature information, fan speed information and voltages.

I have not used this software on windows 10 myself, but I expect it will work and satisfy your need for information.

http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html

It is more of a Real-Time monitor, but it also logs the information it captures. I hope that is what you meant by characteristics.